# Opposite of isnull in mysql

Tags: mysql

To get whether a field is null I can do:

```
select id, isnull(sd_vod_retail_price) from main_territorypricing where title_id=904534727
```

How would I check to see whether a field is not null? Something like:

```
select id, isnotnull(sd_vod_retail_price) ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `!` operator:

```
select id, !isnull(sd_vod_retail_price) from main_territorypricing where title_id=904534727
```